# Coldfusion/Lucee - Loop over 3D array to insert into database using multiple inserts using one query

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I know the title is a mouth-full - sorry about that but trying to be specific here.

DB: MySql  (technically Maria)
ColdFusion (technically Lucee: 5.x)

The array looks like the following:
[image]

NOTE: the outter most array only shows part of 2 and could continue through into the 30's.

I'm looking to perform a loop over the array to insert the elements marked as "string" in the image into the database using one query. Query has been trimmed for the sake of clarity and conciseness:

```
for (outer = 1; outer <= ArrayLen(myArray); outer++) {
    local.currentrow = local.currentrow + 1;
    for (inner = 1; inner <= ArrayLen(myArray[outer]); inner++) {
            local.sql = "
                INSERT INTO table (uuid, typeID, menuId, activityID, userID)
                VALUES (
                    '#local.uuid#',
                    #myArray[outer][inner][1]#, 
                    #myArray[outer][inner][2]#,
                    #myArray[outer][inner][3]#,
                    #arguments.formDataStruct.userID#
            )";  
    queryExecute(local.sql);   
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something along this line but as written, it isn't working:

```
local.sql = "
INSERT INTO table (uuid, typeID, menuId, activityID, userID)
VALUES (
    if (local.currentrow gt 1) {
        ,
    }
    for (outer = 1; outer <= ArrayLen(myArray); outer++) {
        local.currentrow = local.currentrow + 1;
        for (inner = 1; inner <= ArrayLen(myArray[outer]); inner++) {

                    '#local.uuid#',
                    '#myArray[outer][inner][1]#', 
                    '#myArray[outer][inner][2]#',
                    '#myArray[outer][inner][3]#',
                    '#arguments.formDataStruct.userID#'
        }
    })
";
queryExecute(local.sql);
```

The error message I'm getting is

> Element at position `[1]` doesn't exist in array

but if I perform a `writedump[1][3][3]` (e.g.), I'll get the value 24.

Comment: What does not work? There's an exception? MySQL typically prints out something like `error in statement starting with...`.

Comment: Oh, I left that out, didn't I. The error was CF releated stating: `Element at position [1] doesn't exist in array`. Added error message to post.

Comment: Are you sure the error is with that code? Where is `myArray` defined? Worked fine for me, but noticed that variable isn't scoped with "local" and "arguments" like the others. Also, a `for(elem in array)` loop would be more readable than a `from-to` loop   https://trycf.com/gist/1569556843207106fe09123cf5aac703/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: `myArray` is scoped towards the top of the function despite not being shown in the original post here. That is a good catch. I'll add that scoping to my array - maybe that was the problem all along. The from-to-loop approach was gleamed from another SO post so I thought I'd try it. Still learning cfscript loops so I appreciate the gist - that looks very interesting.

Comment: Well, may not be the issue, but it wouldn't help ;-) Is the 3D array a requirement? An array of structures is more intuitive IMO. Also, if you really *were* going to use a `from-to` loop, don't forget to `local` everything, including the loop indexes.

Comment: Ultimately, the query should use queryparams for protection and performance. For now, if you're getting SQL errors, use the `writeDump(local.sql)` to troubleshoot. Copy and paste the generated sql into MySQL and run it. MySQL usually provides more meaningful error messages than CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against looping over an INSERT statement and rather just loop over VALUES to generate a single INSERT statement. A single INSERT will perform *significantly* faster, plus it will minimize the connections to your database.

Build out the list of values with something like:

```
  for (var outer in arguments.inArray) {
    for (var inner in outer) {
      // Concat elements of inner array to a SQL VALUE string. If UUID is supposed to be a unique identity for the row, use Maria's uuid() instead of CF (or skip the UUID insert and let Maria do it).
      // inArray elements and inUserID should be sanitized.
      local.values &= "( uuid(), '" & inner[1] & "','" & inner[2] & "','" & inner[3] & "'," & local.userID & ")," ;
    }
  }
  local.values = left(local.values,len(local.values)-1) ; // Get rid of the last comma.
  local.sql = "INSERT INTO table (uuid, typeID, menuId, activityID, userID) VALUES " & local.values ;
```

After you've built up the SQL INSERT string, execute the query to INSERT the records. (You would probably build the above function differently to handle building the query string and parameters and then executing it all in one place.)

Don't forget to sanitize your array and other inputs. Does the array come from a source you control or is it user input?

https://trycf.com/gist/7ad6af1e84906b601834b0cc5ff5a392/lucee5?theme=monokai
http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d11f45f30723ba910c58a1e3f7a7c30b

Comment: The goal is to use one connection to the DB - I tried to word the question that way but going back and reading again, I can see it needs some improvements. Thank you for the example codes. They are clean, clear, and well documented (sounds like a pimple cream wash). I typically define the arguments params to a variable and then reference the variables (e.g. :typeID, :menuID, :activityID, etc.) when I build out the SQL statements. How would I do that in inside of a loop - or would there be any difference?

Comment: Here is an cleaned up example of what I'm referring to: `local.params = {
            menuID = { value = arguments.formStruct.menuID, cfsqltype = 'CF_SQL_INTEGER' },
            typeID = { value = arguments.formStruct.typeD, cfsqltype = 'CF_SQL_INTEGER' },
            userID = { value = arguments.formStruct.userID, cfsqltype = 'CF_SQL_INTEGER' }
        };` and then my execute SQL statement looks like: `queryExecute(local.sqlqry, local.params);`

Comment: The data is coming from a form via drop down values but the drop down values are supplied by the user from another area of the application.

Comment: I figured out where to sanitize the variables. What an excellent exercise, thank you!